# Need assistant with if else statement

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript, so please help me to understand what is my problem.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var wide = false;
    if(wide = false) {
        document.querySelector(".some-class").onclick = function() {
            document.querySelector("#some-id").className += " MyClass";
            wide = true;
        };
    }
    else {
        document.querySelector(".some-class").onclick = function() {
            document.querySelector("#some-id").className =
            document.querySelector("#some-id").className.replace(/\bMyClass\b/,'');
            wide = false;
        };
    }
}, 1000);
```

This is not working(not adding MyClass). But if I use just this:

```
setTimeout(function() {
document.querySelector(".some-class").onclick = function() {
document.querySelector("#some-id").className += " MyClass";
};
}, 1000);
```

Then it works fine. So what is the problem with my code that not working?

PS:
Thank you. This what I got:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var wide = false;
    if(wide == false) {
        document.querySelector(".some-class").onclick = function() {
            document.querySelector("#some-id").className += " MyClass";
            wide = true;
        };
    }
    else {
        document.querySelector(".some-class").onclick = function() {
            document.querySelector("#some-id").className =
            document.querySelector("#some-id").className.replace(/\bMyClass\b/,'');
            wide = false;
        };
    }
}, 1000);
```

It worked, but now it only add the MyClass on each onclick event and not removing it. I tried to play with else to elseif and tried to move the `wide = flase` and `wide = true` outside the onclick event, but yet this is the same.

Comment: `wide == false`. Use double equals for comparison.

Comment: Your code still isn't working because the function for `onclick` is beneath the if statement, therefore the if statement will have no effect after the first run. To make it better: set the `onclick` to a new function that detects whether the class is wide or not, and then performs certain code based on that.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you have: `if (wide = false) {...`
This is setting `wide` equal to `false`, not comparing values.

To compare values use `==` or `===`.

- Single equals -> Defining/setting variables.
- Double equals -> Comparison with type conversion. Ex: `("2" == 2) // true`
- Triple equals -> Comparison with no type conversion. Ex: `("2" === 2) // false`

For your issue, you can use either double or triple equals.

Comment: Thank you, please see the my post, I still have something wrong

Answer (score 0):

change to  `if(wide === false) {...}`

If you use `=` you are setting `wide` equal to `false`, not comparing the two values for equality. In your case you can either use `==` or `===` to check for equality.

The former (`==`) only compares values, while the latter (`===`) compares values + type.

Comment: Thank you. I edit my post, there's something else wrong with my code.